# Are "Custom Instructions" injected into the context window repeatedly?

Tags: chatgpt, gpt-4

ChatGPT (the conversational front-end to GPT 3.5 and GPT 4) includes user configurable custom instructions. They allocate 1500 characters to "what you would like chatGPT to know about you" and 1500 characters to "how you would like ChatGPT to respond."

How does the system preserve custom instructions as the conversation unfolds? Since the context window is constantly shedding tokens on the back-end on the conversation, I'm wondering if the ChatGPT wrapper is regularly reinjecting these instructions into the context under the hood. It could be happening with each interaction or perhaps it happens every x number of tokens. Does anyone have a clue about how this might work?

Comment: This question would better fit on the GenAI stack exchange.